# Send ATcommand from sim-card to modem(gsm) controller

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command

My apologize if the question is not correct, I'm novice in this topic. I know that AT commands are send to controller of modem by (via)  com port.  My question: Are there modems that can send a AT commands to the modem controller from sim card? And if yes, then what?
P.S.  Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the 3GPP [AT command manual TS 27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm) for standard specified AT commands.
Some of these AT commands are relevant to the SIM, e.g. +CPIN (PIN entry) or +CPBR (phonebook).
TS 27.007 has instructions for using the AT commands, including expected responses from the device.
Some of the AT commands are mandatory, and some are optional - this is written in the spec in the section for each AT command.
If you are looking for AT commands that are sent by the device, check if the AT command is "unsolicited."  This means that the device sends it, and it's not a response to an AT command from the modem controller.

So the answer to your question is, yes, all modems should support at least the mandatory standard AT commands for SIM dialogues like +CPIN.  Most modems will support the optional ones as well, and some may support the manufacturer's own proprietary AT commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking about is what is known as [SIM Application Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Application_Toolkit) where code running on the SIM card is able to initiate communication with the AT command handling part of the phone. The commands are either `proactive` (from SIM application to the modem part) or `envelope` (from modem to SIM).

If you search the web for `sim application toolkit proactive envelope` you will find more information.